# Instagram auth (not login) via Auth0 on React Native?

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth, instagram, auth0

I am building a feature in a React Native application that would allow users to import their photos from Instagram.

This feature is just a small option within the application. I would like to use Auth0 to handle Instagram API access, but I have no interest in their authentication/login/web-form stuff.

I simply want a button saying "Authorise with Instagram" or similar, that triggers an Instagram authentication flow - preferably via the native app itself with deep linking back to my app (not a web form).

I then just need to get the user's feed of images from Instagram somehow. I have seen the [quickstart guides from Auth0 on React Native](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native), but everything seems geared towards authentication/login/web-form.

How is this possible?

Something like:

```
async getInstagramAuth() {

    const token = await auth0.getInstagramToken()
    this.somehowGetInstagramFeed(token)

}

<Text onPress={this.getInstagramAuth}>Authorise with Instagram</Text>
```

Comment: did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to have each person that plans to use your app create an instagram developers account prior to using the app.  In order to get an access token they will need to have a clientId.  I'm not sure if this would work in React Native but there is a login button component for React called react-instagram-login , which will return the accesstoken for that particular account in its callback, but again,  it needs to have a developer account set up.  Here is a link to the repo  https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-instagram-login you can use any oauth2 library technically, and get the accesstoken in the same manner since the login flow for instagram uses that.